# Set clock table duration format for emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I recently upgraded to [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) 8.2.5h and now when I update my clock tables, values that are larger than 24h get for instance displayed as: `1d 9:16`. Is there any preference I can set to switch it back to the hours:minutes format. I've searched the documentation but could not find any information regarding this topic.

Comment: Please consider updating the correct answer, since the customization variables have changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **Before Org-Mode Version 9.1**

You can set the `org-time-clocksum-format` variable like [this](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/80781) :

```
(setq org-time-clocksum-format (quote (:hours "%d" :require-hours t :minutes ":%02d" :require-minutes t)))
```

- **Org-Mode Version 9.1 and up**

You should now use `org-duration-format` :

```
(setq org-duration-format (quote h:mm))
```

See [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-02/msg00270.html) for explanations on the update.

See [this](https://orgmode.org/Changes_old.html#orgb7d7e66) for the Org-Mode release notes.

Answer (score 31):

You should now use `org-duration-format` :

`(setq org-duration-format (quote h:mm))`

for your question.

See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-02/msg00270.html for explanations.

Comment: Just upgraded to the latest stable org and can confirm that this setting works.

Answer (score 25):

[Apparently](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/80781) you can set the `org-time-clocksum-format` variable like this:

```
(setq org-time-clocksum-format (quote (:hours "%d" :require-hours t :minutes ":%02d" :require-minutes t)))
```

Comment: Is it possible that this may not work because of some reason? I had this working. Due to some reason it has stopped working